# What are the effects of formatting on SQL statements in PHP applications?

Tags: php, mysql, formatting, xampp, indentation

I have this bit of PHP code that accesses a database using XAMPP/mysql. I'm setting the query string, both look exactly the same to me besides spacing/tabs but one works and the other doesn't.

This doesn't work:

```
$sql = "UPDATE employees
    SET 
    first_name = '$_GET[firstname]',
    last_name = '$_GET[lastname]',
    hire_date = '$_GET[hiredate]',
    salary = '$_GET[salary]',
    department_id = '$_GET[department]',
    WHERE 
    employee_id = '$_GET[id]'";
```

This works:

```
$sql = "UPDATE employees
        SET 
        first_name      =    '$_GET[firstname]', 
        last_name       =   '$_GET[lastname]', 
        hire_date       =   '$_GET[hiredate]', 
        salary          =   '$_GET[salary]', 
        department_id   =   '$_GET[department]'
        WHERE 
        employee_id     =   '$_GET[id]'";
```

When I use the broken statement I get:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE employee_id = '104'' at line 8

Can anyone explain why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an extra comma in your first example. Basically you made a typo.

```
$sql = "UPDATE employees
SET 
first_name = '$_GET[firstname]',
last_name = '$_GET[lastname]',
hire_date = '$_GET[hiredate]',
salary = '$_GET[salary]',
department_id = '$_GET[department]', // <--- HERE
WHERE 
employee_id = '$_GET[id]'";
```